# Unexpected Logout caused by Xorg Segmentation fault

Tags: 11.04, xorg

Unexpected logout happened on my 11.04 ubuntu, found a segmentation fault message under /var/log/Xorg.0.log.old under inspection. Anyone can point out where should i look for.

```
Backtrace:
[  5559.541] 0: /usr/bin/X (xorg_backtrace+0x26) [0x4a2626]
[  5559.541] 1: /usr/bin/X (0x400000+0x6219a) [0x46219a]
[  5559.541] 2: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x7f409e7e4000+0xfc60) [0x7f409e7f3c60]
[  5559.541] 3: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/librecord.so (0x7f409c199000+0x2920) [0x7f409c19b920]
[  5559.541] 4: /usr/bin/X (_CallCallbacks+0x34) [0x432af4]
[  5559.542] 5: /usr/bin/X (WriteToClient+0x21a) [0x461c9a]
[  5559.542] 6: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libdri2.so (ProcDRI2WaitMSCReply+0x52) [0x7f409bb80d82]
[  5559.542] 7: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libdri2.so (DRI2WaitMSCComplete+0x59) [0x7f409bb7f479]
[  5559.542] 8: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/intel_drv.so (0x7f409b92c000+0x25030) [0x7f409b951030]
[  5559.542] 9: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm.so.2 (drmHandleEvent+0x108) [0x7f409bd8a478]
[  5559.542] 10: /usr/bin/X (WakeupHandler+0x4b) [0x4322fb]
[  5559.542] 11: /usr/bin/X (WaitForSomething+0x1b6) [0x45c786]
[  5559.542] 12: /usr/bin/X (0x400000+0x2e032) [0x42e032]
[  5559.542] 13: /usr/bin/X (0x400000+0x21a7e) [0x421a7e]
[  5559.542] 14: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (__libc_start_main+0xff) [0x7f409d72deff]
[  5559.542] 15: /usr/bin/X (0x400000+0x21629) [0x421629]
[  5559.542] Segmentation fault at address 0x7f4095e5c010
[  5559.542]
Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault). Server aborting
[  5559.542]
```

Comment: What were you doing on the event of crash? What GPU do you have?

Comment: Exact same problem (and log par here) with Intel HD GPU and running Gnome Shell. I suspect some xorg-intel driver issue :(

Comment: Sounds to me like a bug that should be filed to prevent such crashes in the future.

Answer (score 3):

Based on [this post](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=942805#p942805), try disabling record module in Xorg.conf - as the crash backtrace points to librecord:

```
Section  "Module"
    Disable "record"  
EndSection
```

This solved the issue for me.

Comment: Why `librecord`?